# How can I reliably get logs from Event Hub to Splunk

Tags: azure, azure-functions, splunk, azure-eventhub

I want to guarantee delivery of messages from Event Hub to Splunk with no duplicates

I was looking into using Azure Functions because I like the serverless aspect of it, but it seems that Azure Functions progress the Event Hub checkpoint even if the function completes with errors. This would cause a loss of messages if our Splunk instance is down for an extended period of time (API Upgrades, or other unforeseen issues)
The retry policy on azure function triggers on Event Hub events also don't seem to be configurable

Are there other solutions to reliably get messages in Event Hub to Splunk?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are 2 methods from Microsoft for collecting Azure data into Splunk

#### https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureFunctionforSplunkVS

This option integrates with Azure Functions, and as you mentioned, may have issues with failures and retries.

#### https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureMonitorAddonForSplunk

It looks like this option uses a pull mechanism, which should avoid the issue with failures and retires. However, there is a risk that if the add-on fails to run for a significant amount of time, data may roll, and you run the risk of missing data that way.